# How to insert a hex string to a longvarbinary column in hsql?

Tags: sql-insert, hsqldb

How to make this work in HSQL insert script? *Image* column datatype is *longvarbinary*.

```
insert into Item (ID, Image)
values (1, '0xFFD8FFE000104A464');
```

Comment: I'm no expert except at googling :-) so maybe this will help: http://hsqldb.10974.n7.nabble.com/Insert-Into-LONGVARBINARY-td922.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary literal format in SQL language has an X prefix outside the quoted string.

Note the string must have an even number of characters. Your example will work if you add one character to make the string length even.

```
insert into Item (ID, Image) values (1, X'FFD8FFE000104A4640');
```

See http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_literals